# Mysql users compare to itself

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a overview Who owe's who on call hours.
below the table i have.

[image: Table example]

so user 2 has done 9 hours for user 1. but user 1 has done 3 hours for user 2 so the total owing from user 1 is 6 hours. and user 2 is owing user 3, 2 on call hours. how can i  make a cross reference table from all users in Mysql?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a natural thing to do in SQL.  But it is possible.  To make a cross-reference table, you need to generate the rows and then fill the columns:

```
select user_id_a,
       sum(case when user_id_b = 1 then hours_oncall else 0 end) as user_1,
       sum(case when user_id_b = 2 then hours_oncall else 0 end) as user_2,
       sum(case when user_id_b = 3 then hours_oncall else 0 end) as user_3
from ((select user_id_a from t
      ) union
      (select user_id_b from t
      )
     ) u left join
     t
     on t.user_id_a = u.user_id_a
group by u.user_id_a;
```

Comment: so I can't generate the list of users dynamic ? because the users will change over the year?

Comment: @Roelofzo . . . This type of transformation is really better done at the application layer or using a tool such as pivot tables in Excel.  That said, it is possible.

Comment: You can't make the number of columns dynamic.  But you could easily produce a total report with a owes b c hours, with all the combinations (users squared minus users rows)

Comment: @Roelofzo . . . It is possible . . . using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In plain SQL you can't have a dynamic number of columns that adjusts to the number of users, though in your code you could generate SQL that does that.  But I think you are better off just getting rows showing who owes whom how many hours and transforming the data like a pivot table in your code.

To get the basic data, assuming your table is called hours_oncall:

```
select ower,owed,sum(hours_oncall) hours
from (
    select user_id_a ower,user_id_b owed,hours_oncall from hours_oncall
    union all
    select user_id_b,user_id_a,-hours_oncall from hours_oncall
) hours_oncall_union
group by 1,2
having hours>0;
```

which for your sample data, returns:

```
+------+------+-------+
| ower | owed | hours |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    2 |     6 |
|    2 |    3 |     2 |
+------+------+-------+
```